# Typescript class properties with super

Tags: typescript

Transpiling TKO / Knockout.js back to ES3 or ES5 for IE9 compatibility,
 [tko.binding.if/src/ifNotWith.js](https://github.com/knockout/tko/blob/master/packages/tko.binding.if/src/ifIfnotWith.js) an error is encountered here:

```
class ConditionalBindingHandler extends AsyncBindingHandler {
  ...
  get shouldDisplayIf () { return !!unwrap(this.value) }
  ...
}

export class UnlessBindingHandler extends ConditionalBindingHandler {
  get shouldDisplayIf () { return !super.shouldDisplayIf }
}
```

This errors after Typescript is run on it because Typescript changes the `super.shouldDisplayIf` to `super.prototype.shouldDisplayIf`, which changes the `this` reference.

What it should do (for getting, but setting is similar) is something like this:

```
p = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(super, 'shouldDisplayIf')
return 'get' in p ? p.get.call(this) || p.value
```

... but it's not.  Is this a known issue with Typescript, or am I missing something?

The only related issue I could find was: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338

Comment: Indeed [Microsoft/TypeScript#338](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338) looks like the relevant issue.  Do you need anything answered here?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. A relevant answer would indicate that I'm mistaken or missing some information about a workaround, however it looks like you are confirming my research.  If you are confident, please feel free to post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt the link doesn't work (to the github repo)

Comment: @Cody - Thanks, Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a WONTFIX by Microsoft:

> RyanCavanaugh commented on Nov 27, 2017
>
> Long story short - after five years of not having this and people surviving despite it, it seems like ES6 adoption is catching up fast enough that the narrow window of people who target ES5 (rather than 3 for maximum compat or 6 for smallest emit delta) is closing to the point where we don't want to accept a big chunk of helper emit at this point. Open to data otherwise but it just doesn't seem common enough to warrant a big change in the emitter.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338